# How to write/append a file using AppEngine without using Google Cloud Storage (GCS)?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, blobstorage

I need to append a .txt to a Zip File at AppEngine before saving it. 
We are using BlobStore and Servlets.

I found a solution using AppEngine.FileService, but is deprecated. So, it's not a real solution. In the other hand, Google provides as a substitute for FileService the Google Cloud Storage (GCS).

Unfortunately, GCS is a paid service.

Anyone has free solution?

Comment: We figure out how to capture the data from blob using the fetchData method when downloading the file. 
But we don't know yet how to do that before saving the file at AppEngine.